# Upgrading from java 8 breaks serialization Jmeter

Tags: java, spring, jmeter

I am migrating project from Java 8 to Java 17. In version 8, the project uses these libraries for serialization:

```xml
<!-- Spring version -->
<spring.version>5.2.16.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.autoconfig.version>2.6.3</spring.autoconfig.version>
<!-- Jmeter version --> 
<jmeter.version>5.4.1</jmeter.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
        <version>${jmeter.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_java</artifactId>
        <version>${jmeter.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_http</artifactId>
        <version>${jmeter.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

The codebase is using distributed tests in jmeter -> it serializes the objects and send them to remote engines (jmeter).

In Java 17, a new version of spring/jmeter is used (serialization libraries remain the same).

```xml
<spring.boot.version>3.0.2</spring.boot.version>
<spring.version>6.0.4</spring.version>
<jmeter.version>5.5</jmeter.version>
```

The test extends `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` class from spring.

In the Java 8 version, the class is serialized without problem, but in Java 17 the serialization fails on

```
Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext
```

`AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` has

```
@Nullable
protected ApplicationContext applicationContext;
```

field that is probably the reason why it fails, but for Java 8/spring 5.2.16 version it works. What caused this? Is there any workaround in new spring version?

Comment: Can you try updating one step at a time? My first step would be updating to java 11, without changing the library versions (if that's possible)

Comment: @Sören i cant, the project was updated to java 17 ( so there are quite a few places that uses java 17 stuff ), some time ago and im to migrate the distributed tests that havent been looked at for a while.

Comment: So, right now your tests are broken? If that's so, your first order of business should be to get back to a green state. Remove or revert code (locally!) until you have a working codebase again.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [Java Object Serialization](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/serialization/) as implemented by `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`, then there are no guarantees that serializations of Java SE classes and 3rd party classes (e.g. Spring classes) will be stable across different Java versions.

This is one of the drawbacks of using Java Object Serialization.

Will you be able to work around the problem?  It depends on the nature of the incompatibility.

In this case, if you can ensure that the `applicationContext` field is always `null` when you serialize, then serialization and deserialization should both work.

Other options are:

- use a modified version of `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` in which the `applicationContext` field is declared as `transient`, or
- use a different serialization scheme; e.g. JSON, XML, etc.

Note: if you *need* to pass the `ApplicationContext` object to your jmeter service, solving this going to be difficult.  There are probably good reasons why the `ApplicationContext` interface and its implementation classes are not declared as `Serializable`.

Comment: what are the options then  to make it work? Use 3rd serialization service? Or?